# Confluent Control Center shutting down periodically with "exit 1"

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

A Confluent Kafka instance is running via docker-compose on my Debian 9 server. I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html) to get it up and running. However, Control Center is shutting down periodically.

`sudo docker-compose ps` gives the following output:

```
control-center    /etc/confluent/docker/run        Exit 1
```

The rest of the Confluent services stay up and running.

When checking docker logs (`sudo docker-compose logs`) I can see that it is spamming the following error:

```
control-center     | INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-controlcenter-5-3-0-1-9de26cca-62ca-42d6-9d46-86731fc8109a-StreamThread-5-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer)
```

**EDIT**: discovered some more logs:

```
control-center     | [2019-08-30 23:10:02,304] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-controlcenter-5-3-0-1-39ae65e2-457c-4696-b592-504fe320038e-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=_confluent-controlcenter-5-3-0-1] Group coordinator broker:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery 

control-center     | [2019-08-30 22:38:39,291] INFO [Consumer clientId=_confluent-controlcenter-5-3-0-1-39ae65e2-457c-4696-b592-504fe320038e-StreamThread-8-consumer, groupId=_confluent-controlcenter-5-3-0-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
```

**EDIT 2**: memory available to docker containers:

```
NAME                  CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
ksql-datagen          0.00%               3.312MiB / 7.792GiB   0.04%               18.2kB / 2.11kB     92.8MB / 65.5kB     1
control-center        0.00%               0B / 0B               0.00%               0B / 0B             0B / 0B             0
ksql-cli              0.00%               484KiB / 7.792GiB     0.01%               19.6kB / 0B         41kB / 0B           1
ksql-server           0.36%               136MiB / 7.792GiB     1.70%               39.8MB / 34.5MB     210MB / 147kB       30
rest-proxy            0.12%               107.2MiB / 7.792GiB   1.34%               22.2kB / 2.41kB     72.6MB / 81.9kB     28
connect               0.60%               1.571GiB / 7.792GiB   20.16%              124MB / 110MB       1.04GB / 81.9kB     36
schema-registry       0.20%               176.8MiB / 7.792GiB   2.22%               40.2MB / 38.4MB     93.7MB / 156kB      32
broker                7.59%               621MiB / 7.792GiB     7.78%               573MB / 791MB       171MB / 335MB       73
zookeeper             0.10%               80.9MiB / 7.792GiB    1.01%               9.56MB / 8.99MB     38.4MB / 410kB      21
```

System memory (command: `free`):

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     8366596096  6770286592   160227328   219533312  1436082176  1099268096
Swap:   34356588544  2301014016 32055574528
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you allocated Docker plenty of memory (e.g. >=8GB)?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I did not specifiaclly allocate an amount of memory. I edited my original post with the memory usage of the docker containers and my system memory.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes up when the memory allocated is very less.
If you are using Docker Desktop then increase the memory . Go to Docker Desktop->Dashboard->Settings->Preferences->Resources->Advanced and increase the memory and you will be all set.